# How to select option in UWP Xaml Control gallery RadioButton in code behind

Tags: uwp

I am using UWP XAML Control from control gallery. There is no examples on github to select a radio option in c# code behind. Maybe using a DependencyProperty?

[enter link description here](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery)

Example radio button control. How to set a selected radio option? (test.SelectedItem = ??)

```
<muxc:RadioButtons x:Name="test" MaxColumns="2" Header="testing">
<x:String>one</x:String>
<x:String>two</x:String>
</muxc:RadioButtons>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just 2 options in my radio button group, I ended up writing this static code to get it working. I would never be able to do this with dynamic radio buttons. Setting the SelectedItem on UWP RadioButtons needs better documentation. Here's my pseudo code for what I had to do.

```
                foreach (RadioButton item in MyRadios.Items.ToList())
                {
                    switch (MyOptionString)
                    {
                        case "SomeX":
                            MyRadios.SelectedIndex = 0;
                            break;
                        case "SomeY":
                            MyRadios.SelectedIndex = 1;
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**XAML:**

```
<muxc:RadioButtons x:Name="test" MaxColumns="2" Header="testing">
    <RadioButton x:Name="FirstRadioButton" Content="One"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="SecondRadioButton" Content="Two"/>
</muxc:RadioButtons>
```

(Instead of using `<x:String>`, you can use `<x:RadioButton>`, so you can choose a name in code for every `RadioButton`)

Now you can select a `RadioButton` from code, for example:

```
FirstRadioButton.IsChecked = true;
```

The first `RadioButton` will be selected.

**EDIT:**
In your case, you can put in code:

```
AgentRadioButton.IsChecked = true;
```

Comment: How do I make "Agent" the selectedItem in C#?       <muxc:RadioButtons x:Name="ClientMode" MaxColumns="2" SelectionChanged="ClientMode_SelectionChanged" >
                                <RadioButton x:Name="AgentRadioButton" Content="Agent"/>
                                <RadioButton x:Name="CounterRadioButton" Content="Counter"/>
                            </muxc:RadioButtons>

Comment: You can put in your code 'AgentRadioButton.IsChecked = true;' and the user will see "Agent" as the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

> How to select option in UWP Xaml Control gallery RadioButtons in code behind

You have pointed the key(`test.SelectedItem`). Please refer `RadioButtons` xaml sample [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/blob/master/XamlControlsGallery/ControlPages/RadioButtonsPage.xaml.cs#L44), you could listen [`SelectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.radiobuttons.selectionchanged?view=winui-3.0) event, and get which item select with `SelectedItem`.

For example

```
private void BorderBrush_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ControlOutput != null && sender is RadioButtons rb)
            {
                string colorName = rb.SelectedItem as string;
                switch (colorName)
                {
                    case "Yellow":
                        ControlOutput.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gold);
                        break;
                    case "Green":
                        ControlOutput.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGreen);
                        break;
                    case "White":
                        ControlOutput.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Update**

If you want to select item within code behind, please set `SelectedIndex` for `RadioButtons`.

**For example**

```
Radios.SelectedIndex = Radios.Items.ToList().IndexOf("Two");
```

Comment: I'm using the example from Lorenzo, but I still do not see how to make an item selected? The xaml sample doesn't show that.

Comment: Ok, I got it, I have updated the reply and use SelectedIndex  to select radiobutton item.

Comment: Thanks. The IndexOf returned -1. I ended up using a workaround.